# Can I use case method append on Laravel5?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5

I write code like this

```
    $category = Input::get('category'); // ?category=1

    if(!empty($category)){ // ?category=1, category=2
        $lists = \App\Test::where('created_at', '<=', 'now()')
                                 ->where('category', $category) // append this.
                                 ->orderBy('id','desc')
                                 ->get();
    }
    else { // ?category=, category=0
        $lists = \App\Test::where('created_at', '<=', 'now()')
                                 ->orderBy('id','desc')
                                 ->get();
    }
```

That is so work but I think dirty code.
I dont wanna write same code again if I can.

So I wish to do like this ( Not working )

```
    $category = Input::get('category'); // ?category=1

    $lists = \App\Test::where('created_at', '<=', 'now()');

    if(!empty($category)){ // ?category=1, category=2
        $lists .= $lists::where('category', $category);
    }

    $lists .= $lists::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

Anyone know kind solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
 $lists = \App\Test::where('created_at', '<=', 'now()');

    if(!empty($category)){ // ?category=1, category=2
         $lists = $lists->where('category', $category);
    }

   $lists->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

Comment: WORK!! NICE DONE!! Thank you very much ;D

Comment: @qwe001   Mark it as the answer to encourage the Person that helped solve your Problem and also to help visitors with similar problems...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
 $lists = \App\Test::where('created_at', '<=', 'now()');
```

and then when you want to append anything, add it like this:

```
 if(!empty($category)){ // ?category=1, category=2
     $lists = $lists::where('category','=', $category);
 }
```

you don't need to use `.`